# How to access url with random path?

Tags: php, http, url, server

I am using apache2.4.7 on ubunbu14.02 with domain.com, right now all files on root except json under root document, I want to access url like : http sub.mydomain.com/path/randomnumbers?param=xxx to get randomnumbers and param, but couldn't unless it's http sub.mydoamin.com/ or sub.mydomian.com/path, the php respond the request is base64json.php, which put under sub.mydomian.com/base64json.php and sub.mydomian.com/json/base64json.php

I tried to use url rewrite to direct to it, then access the randomnumbers and param in virtual host, then .htaccess, it says:
The requested URL /json/randomnumbers?param=23423424 was not found on this server.

When I put the whole url on a browser, it says:
You don't have permission to access http sub.mydomain.com/json/ldmVudHMiOlt7InNlc3Npb25JZCI6InMxNTAxMjY0OTIzeDYyZjg4MTNlNjkzMWM5eDU4MjQ0MjY2IiwiaW5zdGFudGlhdGlvbiI6IjUwMDYmNyZWF0aXZlTG9hZGVkIiwidmlld2FiaWxpdHkwME1lYXN1cmFibGUiOnRydWUsInZpZXdhYmlsaXR5NTAxTWVhc3VyYWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9XX0= 
on this server.

Here is my virtualhost:

...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^json/ base64json.php [L]

.htaccess under var/www/subdomain/:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^json/ base64json.php [L]

The base65json.php is same as foo.php for the function, then echo the two elements in the array.
 
Any Idea?
Ann

Comment: I don't quite follow your question.  Can you be more explicit and add what you have tried so far (please edit your question)?

Comment: Modified it, basically I need php file under json folder to get the QUERY_STRING and QUERY_PARAM($1)

Comment: Ann, I'm sorry but this is still ambiguous.  You haven't listed any details about your server environment, file hierarchy, code or rewrite rules.

Comment: Added, the server is simple apache+php, not in full swing yet.

Comment: Really difficult to follow this, try removing/renaming the json folder, it may be conflicting with the rewrite rule.

Comment: I put the above two lines in .htacess under: var/www and var/www/track (doc root in virtual host), still the same forbidden with full url.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a simple rewrite rule, and code to parse the uri.

Files

```
.
├── foo.php
└── .htaccess
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^json/ foo.php [L]
```

foo.php

```
<?php

function get_pair($uri) {
    $parsed_url    = parse_url($uri);
    $random_string = end(explode('/', $parsed_url['path']));
    parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $output);
    $param = isset($output['param']) ? $output['param'] : null;

    return array($random_string, $param);
}
var_dump(get_pair($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

Example Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "randomnumbers"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "23423424"
}
```

For:

```
http://localhost/so-rewrite-help/json/randomnumbers?param=23423424&blah=bog
```

foo.php and .htaccess being in so-rewrite-help on my system.

There's probably a more elegant way to extract the parameters from the URI, but this may give you a starting point.

Comment: Mine is  sub.domain.com/json, the base64json.php now is in var/html/sub folder and working. I think rewrite in .htaccess and 000-default.conf <VirtualHost *:80> is not working properly, when I access url, it's still same problems(not found and forbidden), no error in apache2 error.log

Comment: Again it's impossible to know what could be wrong, when you don't include any code.  Do take your time to edit and improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Working now for random-numbers in the url, but still forbidden for base64 in the url(length-344), when I make it shorter, it's working, how to do longer base64encoded url? Thanks!

Comment: @AnnS. glad you got something working.  It sounds like you have hit another problem.  I've glanced stackoverflow and serverfault.  And apparently there is no specified limit to how long a url can be, but you can run into some file system issues:  https://serverfault.com/questions/140852/rewritten-urls-with-parameter-length-255-dont-work  .  Though I don't know if that is your bug.  Post a new question, but please be specific with your server setup, including the OS, as it could well be environment specific.  A workaround might be to change your url format to: json/?encoded=foo&checksum=bar

Comment: No one answers, it seems apache2.4.7 doesn't have it in apache2.conf, I added LimitRequestFieldSize/Line to it, still couldn't go longer than 300 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I added this part, the rewrite is working now:

Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted

Ann